# How i can remove port number in url

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I am using laravel framework in ubunto system and I want to remove port number from my url

write now I can access my web-project with this url

```
http://localhost:8000
```

and I want this url

```
http://localhost/
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run laravel 5 on port 80 of localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592441/how-to-run-laravel-5-on-port-80-of-localhost)

Answer (score 5):

80 is the default port number of http so you have to use this command to omit the port number:

```
sudo php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=80
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
sudo php artisan serve --port=80
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else (e.g. Apache oder Nginx) uses port 80 you COULD start the development webserver like this

```
 sudo php artisan serve --port 80
```

You can access the app via http://localhost/ afterwards

Note that this is ONLY for development and some kind of hack. Install a dedicated webserver (Apache, Nginx) for production :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use php artisan server in your commandline and use full URL path in browsers address bar as follows

```
http://localhost/projectname/public
```

Comment: I can run this http://localhost/abc/public/ but when i redirect on any link http://localhost/jobma/public/contact then i will not work

Comment: Ya i understand the problem. Then , please follow this link http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/