# How to run Laravel 5.4 on port 80 successfully

Tags: laravel, port

I am using a `Laravel` package to connect to a payment system and this particular package sends and receives data via port 80 (and as I use port 8000 to make payments, I will encounter failures).

As seen here:
[How to run laravel 5 on port 80 of localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592721/2922479)

I decided to give it a try but this error is returned:
`Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:80 (reason: Permission denied)`

To discover which program is using port 80, I entered `sudo lsof -i :80` and received the following output:

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 3102     root    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3103 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3104 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3105 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3106 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3107 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3108 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3115 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3116 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 3117 www-data    4u  IPv6  46970      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

I also tried the command: `sudo netstat -nltp | grep -iw "80"` and the following is its output:
`tcp6    0    0 :::80      :::*      LISTEN      3102/apache2`

To free port 80 I tried: `sudo kill -9 3102`, afterwards I ran: 
`sudo netstat -nltp | grep -iw "80"` 
and the output was:
 `tcp6    0    0 :::80      :::*    LISTEN      3330/apache2`
(the port is re-occupied).

I very much like to know how I can use port 80 to develop my Laravel app on it (I am using `Debian 9 Stretch`).

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. I think you are running `artisan server` in the server. It's not recommended to run it on your production server. `artisan server` should only used for development environment.

Based on your explanation, port 80 has been used by `apache2` server. That's normal. What you need to do is to put your Laravel application to apache `DocumentRoot` directory. Because `apache2` is the real web server. For Debian like distribution, `DocumentRoot` for `apache2` located at `/var/www`. You may follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps) guide for more information.

Hope it helps.